# AWS Cognito with Angular 4: Error: Missing region in config

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, console, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a web application which uses AWS services backend size.
In this moment I use AWS Cognito to manage user sessions.
I'm developing the application with Angular 4 (using TypeScript / JavaScript language) and I found this useful class (In the JavaScript SDK for AWS Cognito) that should provide me with so many data that I need to display on the frontend:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

The problem is that any method I invoke on this object, the console return this error:

```
Error: Missing region in config
at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (event_listeners.js:91)
at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:105)
at callNextListener (sequential_executor.js:95)
at event_listeners.js:85
at finish (config.js:315)
at Config.getCredentials (config.js:360)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (event_listeners.js:80)
at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:101)
at Request.emit (sequential_executor.js:77)
at Request.emit (request.js:683)
```

I do not understand why this happens, because I have correctly configured the region, like this:

```
//Setting AWS credentials
AWS.config.region = environment.region;
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId : environment.identityPoolId
});
```

and if i use the instruction `console.log(AWS.config.region)`, the console prints the correct region.

Why it continues to visualize that error?

The complete code:

```
var params = {
UserPoolId: environment.clientId,
};

//Setting AWS credentials
AWS.config.region = environment.region;
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId : environment.identityPoolId
});

this.cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(AWS.config.region)

  if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

the path is always console.log(err) and the error is always Missing region in config. *Why does this continue to happen?*

Answer (score 2):

How about if you do:

```
var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
var client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: 'us-east-1' });
```

and you call listUsers on the client object? I believe region should be passed along when you initialize the service client.

Answer (score 0):

This question is from a while ago, but this worked for me:

When you load the AWS SDK in order to create the AWS instance, you probably have to set the region there, like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-1',
}); 

function(){
  var identityService = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
          apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
 });   

 ...

}
```

Note that you might also have to set your credentials, depending on the action. In this case, you can use code like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-1',
  accessKeyId: process.env.YOUR_ACCESSKEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.YOUR_SECRETKEY
}); 

  function(){
     var identityService = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
          apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
     });   

     ...

}
```